# Community user instantly rejected suggested edit?

Tags: support, edits, review, suggested-edits, community-user

> **No, this isn't another user improving the edit.** Sorry to those who thought they could get easy rep :)

Over on Physics.SE, I made a suggested edit - [#17486](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17486).

I admit that it wasn't the best edit (I made a mistake in the formatting), but the Community user just came along and casted a binding reject vote.

Now, I know that the Community user does this when I am reviewing edits on sites where I'm 2k (here and SO), and I click the Improve button and deselect the 'this edit is helpful' checkbox.

When this happens, however, the Community user rejects the edit, then another entry for the user that chose the improve option is also show above the binding reject vote.

That's not what happened here - I suggested the edit at 20:45, and the CU rejected it at... 20:45. No entry for someone clicking the Improve button.

#### Did the bot gain intelligence and is stalking me? Should I be worried? Does someone at SE need to taze the server that is Community?

Comment: Community is an evil bot... but there is one thing that can bring it down. You must fiIfEsflijS##*2fj911qfslf9J)#fj -- _edited by Community ♦_

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: I see these questions with some frequency, so have [proposed an FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits) about it.

Comment: @knights *Resists temptation to up vote only the CW'ed answer*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, it's a case of another user who was editing while you were editing. You suggested your edit at 20:45:20, then Ben Crowell (who apparently was already editing at the same time) [submitted his edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/67313/revisions) at 20:45:51 which caused Community to immediately reject your edit in favor of his. This also matches the timestamp on the rejection of your suggested edit.

Comment: Kind of sucks for you, though, because apparently all he did was add a homework tag. Ouch.

Comment: So are you really saying it took Ben more than 30 seconds to *add a tag*?

Comment: @Undo: Who knows what he was doing. He *was* in the full edit screen, though, because that's the only way he could have added that edit reason in there. Apparently he was just sitting on it.

Comment: Would you say this is a bug? It feels buggish.

Comment: Well, it's by-design that a user with full editing privileges will always trump a suggested edit if they were already editing the post when your suggestion got submitted. The usual "your edit must be more substantial" rule that would catch multiple users with full privileges editing doesn't apply to suggestions.

Comment: Shoot. It's terrible having to earn 2k everywhere I want any power. Oh well. Thanks!