# How actually edit has been approved or disapproved?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

This is not the duplicate of **[Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)**

I know that there is a 5 min grace period for a question in which every edits will be rejected by Community user automatically.

[Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)

but while going through other question following edits which has been approved after a minute of question asked.(please see this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19115737/revisions) )

- I just want to know what is process of approving edits?
- Is there reputation cap for rejection by community user?

Comment: Am I missing something? The person who edited revision 2 has enough reputation to not require reviews.

Comment: I can't find **any** edits on this post by you - suggested or otherwise.

Comment: @Oded the OP here missed the concept of suggested edits.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I find the whole question to be confused and confusing. I don't really know what the relationship between the question linked and what the OP is asking is.

Comment: @Oded so there is some rep cap for editing means if a certain user have certain reputation they can edit any time and a user has less then that then cannot edit in the grace period ??

Comment: @Oded i will try to improve my question

Comment: The grace period has nothing to do with edit permissions. Users above a certain rep can edit any post. Users under it need to go through an approval process to their edits. Either of these has nothing to do with the grace period, which is an amount of time the _original poster_ can edit their post and in which we do not record the edits. You seem to be conflating the concepts.

Comment: @Oded that is what i asked .. what is the process behind it .. and you are right i was confused about grace period and community user rejection and everything about edit and suggested edit but because of the comments and answer now i am pretty much clear about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a user has over 2000 reputation, they can edit posts without requiring review (the edit is applied immediately). This edit was not a suggested edit. It was not approved; it didn't need to be because the user had 2000+ rep.

You also appear to be confused about Community's rejections. Community will ONLY reject edits when

- Someone with 2000+ rep edits while yours is still pending review
- Someone chooses the "Improve" option in the suggested edits review queue and marks your edit as unhelpful

Comment: ok i got the point .. thx for the clarification

Comment: @Dhaval You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 6):

You got it all wrong.

- The grace period has nothing to do with suggested edits.
- The reason Community user reject edits is *edit conflicts* - when 2K+ user edit is conflicting with suggested edit, the suggested edit is kicked out and auto rejected. It can happen long after any grace period.
- A suggested edit is approved in three cases only:

  1. Three users (on Stack Overflow, two on other sites) approve the edit.
  2. OP or moderator approves the suggested edit with a binding vote.
  3. One user chooses to Improve the suggested edit and ticks the "this edit was helpful".

Also to address another question:

> Is there reputation cap for rejection by community user

No, edit suggested by a user with 1999 points can be rejected exactly the same way as edit made by a user with 1 point.

Comment: Wow, you answered **one second** before me :P

Comment: 4. Moderator approves the suggested edit with bind approval.

Comment: @Doorknob yeah, but your answer give some different aspects. Nice!