# suggested-edit doesn't show correct edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

The [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3192371) was rejected by community.

However, the edit shows incorrect.  I added the line which shows

---

and your call would be

```
ShowMessage(message As String, type As MessageType)
```

---

This line was put into the answer, but my edit was rejected.  I'm not sure what happened and why the edit shows incorrect.  Can someone explained what happened here?

Comment: I have seen this happen before. It was probably because the original answerer updated the post, thus pushing your edit out, rending it irrelevant. This is very probable since your's was rejected within the 5min edit window... **SEE** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits

Comment: @JoshC thanks for the link.  Based on that it looks like the user didn't check the box that my suggestion was helpful and then used it verbatim, therefore **Community** rejected it.  Does that sound feasible?

Comment: I haven't been in such a situation, but yea, that sounds feasible - that's probably what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP made an edit to their own post that was submitted just after your edit was submitted.  This caused your suggested edit to be automatically rejected by the system; someone with full edit privileges "wins" in such situations.