# Can we improve the way edits are working

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Quite often it happens to me that I suggest an edit which adresses several issues with the post, improve them and have a suggested edit hanging in the review queue. While this edit is being reviewed (and usually being approved), others with edit priviledges are making the same / very similar improvements and my suggestion gets auto rejected by this community guy :)

While I do not have any issue with my posts being reviewed, it feels like a shame that the whole work is being done several times when somebody else is doing the same fix.

One example happened a few minutes ago. I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3567055) to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542562/which-is-the-better-way-of-consuming-a-webservice), and while this was hanging in the review queue for about 15 minutes, a very similar edit was done overwriting the suggested edit.

I understand that for edits around the same time those clashes can occur and work will be wasted, but why is there no mechanism which indicates that there is a pending edit which could be approved, modified, rejected by the 2k+ user who wants to edit that question or answer?

Comment: check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits

Comment: Hm, what you suggest already exists, there is an indicator for pending edits, and 2K+ users can improve the suggested edit if they wish. Perhaps you fell victim to a race condition?

Comment: @Yannis Hmm, must have been a 15min race condition :) But does this indicator also give the option to the 2k+ user to verify /adopt that edit or is it just an indicator that a pending edit exists?

Comment: @Matthias: if the 2k+ user starts editing before you submit your suggestion, they'll never see any indication it exists at all. They can't start after you suggest it; they'll be taken to the Review screen instead of being allowed to edit.

Comment: @wooble thanks this covers it then very well. So the risk remains then only for the time man edit is open. Quite acceptable then.

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution for this would be to temporarily "lock" the post from being edited **as soon as 2K+ user, or the OP, starts to edit**.

Message like this will appear as tooltip of the disabled "edit" link and as error for those directly reaching the edit page:

> this post is being edited, please try again later

And the post edit will be unlocked when: (Editor being the 2K user or OP)

1. Editor submits his edit.
2. Editor leaves the edit page without submitting.
3. Five minutes pass.

I'm pretty sure "edit lock" was discussed before but just in case, I give my own idea to be here. :)

Comment: Nah, this is of course nothing anybody would want :) I just know the sub 2k feature of locking a post if there is a pending suggested edit. And as my post was rejected 15min after my suggested edit had been submitted, I thought that there is no (or at least no mandatory) step for a 2k+ to see my edit before discarding it. Did not think about that the other edit maybe was open for so long. Since this step exists as @Wooble explained to me, this was just a case of bad luck, so no need for an improvement here.