# Does it count against me if Community ♦ rejects my edit because it conflicted with a subsequent edit?

Tags: support, community-user, rejected-edits

From time to time, I see [the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1) rejecting edits and giving this reason:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

Would I get an edit ban if I suggest a sufficent number of edits that "conflict with subsequent edits"? I checked out [the FAQ entry about Community ♦ approving & rejecting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/329351), but couldn't find any info about that.

Comment: Short answer: it does not