# How can the Community user review a Low Quality post?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts, community-user

I was reviewing an old post I flagged and saw that the Community user reviewed this post as "Looks OK."  I know the Community user can [approve and reject edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/242209), but in what scenario can the Community user review Low Quality posts?

[image: Reviews]

Comment: I assume this is what happens when a user is deleted who reviewed the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a user gets deleted, their review actions are reassigned to the Community user. The Community user did not actually take any action on the review item - an actual user did. They're just no longer around to display there.

I've personally never liked how this is handled in review, as it's inconsistent with how we would normally display deleted users on the site (their userX display name in plain text). But the ReviewTaskResults table in the database does not have a denormalized DisplayName field that we can populate when a user is gone, only an actual ID field. So it gets changed to -1 instead and thus the Community user gets shown.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  Do you know if there is an open feature request to show the user's name in plain text rather than the community user?  If not, I'd like to open one.

Comment: @JAL Since I can't find a meta dupe for this question, I think not -- probably no one has cared/noticed since very few active reviewers request account deletion.

Comment: @hichris123 Ok, I've added a feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284137/242209.