# How can Community♦ improve edit suggestions?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, community-user, improve-edit

The reviewer stats on Stack Overflow about the Community♦ user say the following:

> [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) has approved 351480 edit suggestions and rejected 182464 edit suggestions and improved 1492 edit suggestions

And here are the same stats on Super User:

> [Community](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community) has approved 9742 edit suggestions and rejected 2028 edit suggestions and improved 19 edit suggestions

As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993/349538), the approved edits are from when a user reviewed the edit as Improve, and the rejected edits are from when a user reviewed the edit as Reject and Edit or when the edit conflicted with a subsequent edit. But how could Community improve an edit suggestion? Usually when Community edits a post it's an anonymous user who edited it, but anonymous users can't review suggested edits.

So my question is, how could Community♦ improve those edit suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this happens when a reviewer chooses "Improve Edit", but the reviewing user is later deleted.

For example, [this edit history](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/20344/revisions). Revision #2 is by Community, implying that a reviewer chose "Improve Edit". Revision #3, which would then be done by the reviewer, is instead done by a now-deleted user.

These reviews still have to be credited to someone, and Community is the natural choice.

Comment: In your example, the Community approve wasn't given because the editor was anonymous (not deleted, btw), it was given because user2213 improved the edit in rev 3, and Community automatically approves the queued suggested edit that was improved. Community will approve an edit any time a reviewer chooses "improve edit", and will reject an edit any time a reviewer chooses "reject and edit". Note that the improvement is still attributed to the deleted user. Only the previous *approve* is attributed to Community (which is the case even when the editor still exists). Edit **2** is Community, not 3.

Comment: I.e. it's not deleted users, it's *anonymous* users, and your example is the correct example, but the interpretation of it was off. The community *edit* on rev 2 is what you're talking about, but not the community *approve* on rev 2. See https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2488. That example is two things happening at once. Rev 3 doesn't actually have an impact on the fact that Community authored rev 2. Rev 3 only has an impact on the fact that Community also *approved* rev 2, independently.