# Why do edits from Community require approval?

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits, community-user

[This revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/299313/revisions) has Community User as an **editor**, not a reviewer*, and it even has summary of its edit:

[image: Community user made an edit]

So I think that there is actually a human behind this. But even so, why would its edit need to be approved?

In the [approvement page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/53364), it appears as an anonymous user:

[image: proposed by an anonymous user]

---

<sup>*So it's not a dupe of [Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/260800)</sup>

Comment: Your answer is right there in the details you provided. It was proposed by an anonymous user. Community just owns the edit if it gets approved.

Comment: @animuson but why not just display "anonymous user" at the revision page?

Comment: We want to avoid using unlinked anonymous text as much as possible. Community is used for a variety of tasks when a relevant user is unavailable. That's its purpose.

Comment: @animuson I see. Bit why should unlinked anonymous text be avoided?

Comment: presumably its messy (and might make databases have null values where its messy). ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community owns things that aren't owned by any other user.

Anonymous edits, by definition, do not come from logged-in users.

Therefore, Community owns them.  And because they came from people who don't have enough reputation to directly edit posts, they need to be approved.