# How do I unsubmit my own edit from review?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I made an edit that was submitted for review and quickly noticed I made a mistake. How can I unsubmit it?

Comment: Mistake meaning you shouldn't have submitted the edit at all or mistake meaning you left something out/needed to redo the edit?

Comment: The later in this case but I was assuming that I would unsubmit the whole edit and resubmit later rather than redo the edit in place.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you can actually just hit the "edit" button again and re-edit your edit. I've done that a couple of times in the past. Other than that, I don't think there's a way to retract an edit suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your suggested edit by clicking "Edit" on the post again. Any changes you make will become part of your original suggested edit. I think this is what you want.

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to completely retract suggested edits, so if you want to do *that*, you have to contact another user with permissions to edit posts. Usually, they will perform some other concurrent edit, so that your suggestion gets [automatically rejected as an edit conflict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits) and doesn't count negatively towards you.