# Can a moderator overrule a suggested edit approved by the Community user?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, moderators, improve-edit, edit-override

I'm aware of what's explained in the answer to "[Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/286501)".
However, consider a suggested edit review scenario which looks like so:

```
ModeratorX♦ reviewed this MMDD-3 at HH-3:MM-3: Reject
User2       reviewed this MMDD-2 at HH-2:MM-2: Approve
User1       reviewed this MMDD-1 at HH-1:MM-1: Approve
```

The above scenario is what I'd call a fully approved (by User1 and User2) suggested edit, which later on got [overruled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/295232) by a moderator (rejected by ModeratorX♦).

As a variation to the above scenario, consider this scenario:

```
User1      reviewed this MMDD-5 at HH-5:MM-5: Edit
Community♦ reviewed this MMDD-4 at HH-4:MM-4: Approve
```

The above is what I'd call a Community approved suggested edit (by Community♦ and User1). It typically happens if the reviewer of the suggested edit (User1) uses the review action "Improve edit" (instead of just approving it).

**Question**: Can a moderator overrule such "Community approved suggested edit" (similar to the first scenario)? If so, where can I find 1 sample of such review?

Note: Obviously, a moderator can always perform related actions such as an additional edit and/or a rollback, but that is not what my question is about.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

In the specific case you describe, performing a "review and edit" (whether the review is approve or reject) creates a second edit. Moderators and OPs can only override reviews if the suggested edit that was either approved or rejected is the *most recent* edit. Once an additional edit has been submitted, the only recourse is to roll it back or manually edit the post. This is true in all cases, not only the one you describe.

This is explained in more detail in the [suggested edits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/284336) under the "Someone suggested an edit to my post, and the reviewers took the wrong action. What can I do?" section.

> **You cannot override the outcome if:**
>
> - Another edit was made to the post after review completed.
> - The reviewer chose to Improve Edit or Reject and Edit.
> - The review you're trying to override has already been overridden.