# What's the difference between Community♦ and user0?

Tags: support, community-user

(https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/111499 shows action by both.) [Edit: At first glance they both looked like special users.  Not so.]

Comment: "user0" is just a normal, freeform username. The reason why the Community user reviewed the edit is explained at [Why does the Community user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)

Comment: What about "user0" makes them look different than a normal user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key difference is that their real user numbers, respectively, are -1 for Community♦ and 186471 for user0 (on webapps, and thus *not* 0), as can be seen in the URL (classically displayed in a browser's status bar when mousing over the usernames) that clicking on the name opens.

[Community♦](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1) (/community is tacked on the end of the canonical URL) is [a special user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user).

But [user0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/186471) (/user0 is tacked on the end of the canonical URL) is a normal user who just happens to have "0" in the username. user0 approved the edit before it was improved by a different user.

[I found no true user 0 - no user with ID 0](https://stackexchange.com/users/0/anything) on any SE sites.
[There is also no user with ID 1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/1) on some SE sites, but
[there IS a user with ID 1](https://stackexchange.com/users/1) on other SE sites.

Comment: All of the sites with "no user ID 1" had such users at their beginnings, but those users later deleted their accounts.

Answer (score 5):

Community♦ is [a special user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user). Community is credited for reviews when they are:

- Done by deleted users
- Improved, in which case Community is shown as having approved the edit
- Rejected and edited, in which case Community is shown as having rejected the edit

[user0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/186471/user0) is a normal user who just happens to have "0" in the username. user0 approved the edit before it was improved by a different user.

Comment: @MatthewElvey users with a negative ID (e.g. -1 for Community) are special users. Normal users (e.g. 186471 for user0) have a positive ID.

Comment: @MatthewElvey Rejected edit *suggestions* don't show up in revision lists. You need to look at your [edit suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/218120/matthew-elvey?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Or I can be nice and link you. ;) https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/63581