# Why is the Community User the sole approver of this tag wiki suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, community-user

My [suggested edit](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/118) for the tag wiki of the [[login]](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/login/info) tag on [Literature Meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/) seems to have been approved solely by the [Community User](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community):

> [image: Screenshot of review page showing Community User as sole approver of the [login] tag's wiki suggested edit]

What gives?

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, so I've tagged it as [support].

---

#### Further info

Based on [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251), taking any action (except Skip) on a suggested edit review will definitely log that action. For instance, [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/116) is a tag wiki suggested edit that the moderator [Tsundoku](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2191/tsundoku) reviewed around the same time by clicking on "Improve Edit" — it shows "Edit" next to Tsundoku and "Approve" next to Community.

> [image: Screenshot of review page of the suggested edit on the [rss] tag's wiki showing that Tsundoku chose "Improve Edit"]

From the same link, there is one case in which the Community User appears as the sole reviewer, namely when there is a clash of editing between a user with privileges and one without privileges. But, in that case the Community User will reject the edit, not approve. Furthermore, I suggested my edit on the [login] tag's info at 2020-07-30 14:19:10Z and the edit on the wiki was approved by the Community User at 2020-07-30 14:42:59Z, which is late enough. I'm also pretty sure that no other edit was going on at that time.

This also does not seem to be a case of the Community User taking credit for a deleted user's review, as mentioned in [Why does the Community user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992). This is because [this edit](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1346/3) made by Tsundoku on the [login] tag's wiki has the same timestamp as the approval by the Community User. Definitely no other user, deleted or otherwise, was involved in this process.

Could someone explain how it happened that the Community User was the sole approver on my suggested edit on a tag wiki? I took Tsundoku's help in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/conversation/experimenting-with-tag-wiki-suggested-edits) to try and play with the various options that are visible on a tag's info page for approving a suggested edit; however, we couldn't come to any fruitful conclusion.

Comment: *When one is reviewing suggested edits, there are five available buttons, two of which allow the reviewer to edit the post themselves. If the reviewer chooses "Improve Edit" and submits their improved form of it, the suggested edit is approved by Community (and immediately replaced by the improved one).*

Comment: @Catija Yes, but shouldn't the reviewer's name also appear in the review page as in my second screenshot?

Comment: @Catija - that lists the (human) reviewer, though, as "Improve". This shows *solely* the Community user as reviewer.

Comment: @Brahadeesh No? It says "is approved by Community" not "is approved by the reviewer and Community". The timestamps make it pretty clear that Tsundoku's improvement of your edit caused the suggested edit to the Tag Wiki to be approved.

Comment: @Catija - [here's an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/73271). It shows both the reviewer and Community.

Comment: @Mithical Maybe it's a special treatment because the reviewer was a mod... OPs and mods have unilateral reviewing and the OP isn't named in a review approved by them, no?

Comment: @Catija I'm sorry, but I don't follow you. I have (apparently) two instances of Tsundoku choosing "Improve Edit" - in one case, only Community User is listed as a reviewer with "Approve" next to it, in another case both Community User and Tsundoku are listed as reviewers, with "Approve" next to Community User and "Edit" next to Tsundoku. Clearly something is different between the two cases.

Comment: @Catija - they are, without Community - just the OP in the same box around their name as in comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? See: ["Sometimes the Community user approves or rejects my edit."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/282094), and its link: [Why does the Community user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/282094)

Comment: @Rob No, it does not, for the reasons I have given in the body of my question.

Comment: @Rob I'm sorry, I don't understand... I know about the UI change that posts the "does this answer your question" comment automatically on voting to close as duplicate, but I don't understand the meaning of the latter half of your comment, nor the significance of those links.